# Rounding to the nearest hundered-thousandths

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm facing an issue while trying to round up the decimal places in a number to the nearest hundered-thousandth digit.

Example :

```
BigDecimal num1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.38871551);
MathContext mc = new MathContext(5);
System.out.println(num1.round(mc));
```

The output is `0.38872` which is as expected. All good so far. Let's take another example :

```
BigDecimal num1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1680418);
MathContext mc = new MathContext(5);
System.out.println(num1.round(mc));
```

The output is `1.1680`. This is where the problem arrises. What I want is the output to be `1.16804` but the rounding seems to eat up the `4` instead of leaving it as it is.

I tried different rounding modes but this is what I get :

- `RoundMode.UP` gives `1.1681`
- `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` or `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` give `1.1680`
  and so on..

How do I get the desired output :

- `0.38871551` should round to `0.38872`
- `1.1680418` should round to `1.16804`
- `0.55052984` should round to `0.55053`

I even tried rounding to the 6th decimal place instead of the 5th but I'm not able to find the right combination that gives me the desired output as shown above.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it with setScale Function of BigDecimal

```
num1 = num1.setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: This works as well. But why `HALF_UP` and not `HALF_EVEN` like the other answer?

Comment: `HALF_UP` rounds up the digit to the next higher number but `HALF_EVEN` although similar to `HALF_UP` rounds to the nearest even number when equidistant to both numbers. See docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Changed mine to HALF_UP as well... but it's all a matter of what you need. Anyway,  `setscale(int, RoundingMode)` should be preferred over `setscale(int, int)`.

Answer (score 2):

`MathContext(int)` rounds the number to that amount of digits, taking the whole number into account instead of just the digits after the comma.

say you use these numbers:

```
    BigDecimal ten = BigDecimal.valueOf(10.55052984);

    MathContext five = new MathContext(5);
    MathContext two = new MathContext(2);

    System.out.println(ten.round(five));
    System.out.println(ten.round(two));
```

It will produce a number rounded to the 5th or 2nd digit, regardless of its position:

> 10.551
>   11

This should work:

```
    BigDecimal num1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.38871551);
    System.out.println(num1.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

    num1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1680418);
    System.out.println(num1.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

    num1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.55052984);
    System.out.println(num1.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

> 0.38872
>   1.16804
>   0.55053

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. Will this always work correctly as per the rounding rules of mathematics for any number? Also, I tired this approach by using a `Mathcontext` and `round` method. Why does this give the desired output when you use `setScale` but doesn't give the desired output when you use `round` with a `MathContext`?. Also, why `HALF_EVEN` and not `HALF_UP`?

Comment: `MathContext(5)`simply means the whole number is 5 digits long. So a number between 10 and 99  would only have three more digits.

Comment: @Ping I've added an explanation to the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");

System.out.print(df.format(1.1680418)); //1.16804
```